# Sums of the form $\pm1^2\pm2^2\pm3^2\pm4^2\pm...\pm(N-1)^2\pm N^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

There is a string of numbers: $1^2,2^2,3^2,4^2,...,(N-1)^2,N^2 $
We put $+$ (pluses) and $-$ (minuses) in a certain way between them. And calculate the sum.
Can the sum be:

1. $12$, if $N = 12$;
2. $0$, if $N = 70$;
3. $0$, if $N = 48$;
4. $-3$, if $N = 90$;

I solved only b). It is obvious that parity of this sum is the same as in case if all signs between the numbers were pluses. So with $N = 70$ there are $35$(odd number) of pairs ($1^2+2^2$,$3^2+4^2$,etc) that are odd. So the sum is odd.That means we never get $0$

My problem is that in other cases the same logic doesn't work.
Also tried modulo $3$ reasoning.

Is the answer 'yes' to any of the questions?  And how else can we show that the answer is 'no'?  Please show the logic of your thoughts and how you came up to that solution. I really need it to learn to work out such problems by myself.

Comment: Please, try to make the title of your question more informative. E.g., *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: Thanks you!, but apparently I need help choosing a good title. Because everything that I invented was informative but too long.

Comment: What about this? Sums of the form $\pm1^2\pm2^2\pm3^2\pm4^2\pm...\pm(N-1)^2\pm N^2$ `Sums of the form $\pm1^2\pm2^2\pm3^2\pm4^2\pm...\pm(N-1)^2\pm N^2$`

Comment: Excellent!, now will be trying to invent something like this with my new questions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note that for any $a$ we have
$$a^2-(a+1)^2-(a+2)^2+(a+3)^2=4,\tag{1}$$ 
and reversing the signs gives $-4$. So a suitable choice of signs on $b^2$ to $(b+7)^2$ gives sum $0$. Since $48$ is divisible by $8$, a positive answer to c) follows.

A positive answer to d) also follows, since we can use $1^2-2^2$, and then produce $0$ from a suitable choice of signs on the next $88$ consecutive squares. This can be done since $88$ is a multiple of $8$.

We can also easily get a positive answer to a) from Identity (1), since $12=4+4+4$.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you are allowed to use a computer, but since there are only $2^{12}=4048$ possible solutions for (a), it is possible to find the answer using a simple program that checks all possible combinations of pluses and minuses and finds one that sums to $12$. It exists:

$$-1-4-9-16+25+36+49-64-81+100+121-144$$

Comment: Very nice method ! , though I'l be only allowed to use a piece of paper at the exam, to which I am preparing on problems like in this question.

Comment: @user186421 Then Andre's method is probably closer to what you need...  Also, my method fails for $N=48$, where checking all $2^{48}$ combinations is impossible...

Comment: @5xum - Impossible? Maybe with that attitude...

Comment: @Dason Even if checking the $2^{48}\approx 10^{14}$ possibilities is possible, it surely is not for $2^{90}$ which has almost $30$ digits...

Comment: Not with that attitude it's not.